# Simple redirect rules for Amazon S3

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using S3 and CloudFront to store the images, CSS and JS files of my web site - which is not static and is hosted on a proper web server

Since the CSS file changes frequently, I'm using a version number to make sure the user browser reloads it when it changes. When I was hosting the CSS file on my Apache web server, I was using the following redirect rule

```sh
RewriteEngine On
# CSS Redirection (whatever.min.5676.css is redirected to whatever.min.css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.min\.[0-9]+\.css$ $1.min.css
```

With this simple rule, `http://www.example.com/all.min.15.css` redirected to `http://www.example.com/all.min.css`

How can I reproduce such a rule with Amazon S3 and/or CloudFront ?
i.e. to have `http://example.amazonaws.com/mybucket/css/all.min.3.css` or `http://example.amazonaws.com/mybucket/css/all.min.42.css` redirected to `http://example.amazonaws.com/mybucket/css/all.min.css`

(Note : my S3 bucket is NOT configured as a website but should it be so to enable redirection rules?)

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE: this answer does not use any rule. It might not be the proper answer.*

I would be using a query parameter to handle different versions, like:

```
http://example.amazonaws.com/mybucket/css/all.min.css?ver42
http://example.amazonaws.com/mybucket/css/all.min.css?42
http://example.amazonaws.com/mybucket/css/all.min.css?ver=42
http://example.amazonaws.com/mybucket/css/all.min.css?20141014
```

To be exact, in my dynamic web page, the version parameter is stored in a variable and appended to url (both CSS and JS). While in development I only have to increase/set one variable to force the browser to load a new version. This way, there is no need for rewrite rules, even on Apache.

Caching also works as the `Last-Modified` and `ETag` headers are kept in tact.

Hope this helps.